# How to create a domain alias (mapping)

Tags: .htaccess, alias

I am looking to map a xxxxx.com to aaaaa.com. They would be hosted on the same server. I just would xxxxx.com to be an alias for aaaaa.com. So if you want to login at aaaaa.com/login.php you can just as easily do it via xxxxx.com/login.php (having xxxxx.com showing in the address bar).

Is this possible and if so how?

Thank you very much,

Cei

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it within `.htaccess`, but within a http.conf `<VirtualHost>` section you can use the [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) and [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) directives to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, you could take a peek at the ServerAlias directive.